# Comparing NULL values in Java

Tags: java, algorithm, programming-languages

I have a code that compares data but that data contains null values not blank spaces ("") they may/may not be same i guess but I tried comparing repetitive NULL values like

```
         for(int i=0;i<length;i++)
      {
    String data=sample_data.getData();// contains about 
       1000 null rows
    if(data.equals(null) || data.equals("") || data== null 
     ||data.isEmpty())
      System.out.print("No Data"); 

   }
```

I could have used `.contains` but that wont work because it is in the loop.
None of the method makes it print the output as `No Data`   I have tried using `try catch` as well because in order to make sure if theres any error found and was correct at the same time `isEmpty()` and `.equals(null)` were somewhere or the other throwing the exception as NULL but even after removing and simply using `==Null` realizing the fact that data is itself null and comparing like `null.equals` wont work but in case of `==` I found that the error exception got changed to value as 1 thereafter the same error and I wasnt able to recognize this.
Its the sample here which I am showing I cant post the exact but the above makes quite clear. Is there any other way I could treat these `NULL` values.

Note: I dont want to use a loop to iterate data as well and each time comparing `NULL` values because already theres an outer loop for large set of values dont go by the sample code.

Comment: View > Connections. If that doesn't work, Windows > Restore Windows to Factory Settings.

Answer (score 1):

Restoring **windows** to factory settings will restore **windows** (as its name suggests); it won't *spoil* anything.

Comment: yeah at first even i thought it wont affect because it is the view of the window but my datab

Comment: Hmm?  The question is about comparing null values in Java.

Comment: @another-dave, at the time I posted my message, it was valid. Have a look at history of the question's editing - you'll see that revision #2 actually *was* what I was answering to (as well as what thatjeffsmith commented under the question). I don't know why the OP changed the question in such a drastic way, instead of opening a new one.

Comment: @Littlefoot - aha. I had checked, but not carefully enough; "version 1" of the question was not expanded until I noticed and clicked on the ```[>``` marker.

Answer (score 0):

In this

```
       String data=sample_data.getData();// contains about 1000 null rows
       if(data.equals(null) || data.equals("") || data== null
```

you are apparently concerned that `data` may be null.

If indeed it is null, then the very first clause in your `if` statement will throw a null pointer exception... because you can't call the `equals` method on a null reference.

You want

```
       if (data == null || data.isEmpty())
```

and that covers all the cases of nothing, except possibly the case where data is "some number of space characters", but I'll leave that for you.